# nanosecond electronic pulser circuit - up to 100MHz

Tags: generator, pulse

I would like to create a circuit which creates nanosecond pulses for a trigger signal with a frequency from 20 to 80 MHz, at 3.3V. I have created the following cricuit as can be seen in the attatched image.
Since this is a new design, would it work to get output singnals at the 50 ohm resistor of nanosecond width with each trigger signal (TTL 3.3V)?

- Should I change the decoupling capacitors or do they seem to be correctly selected?
- For the LT1021-5 should I change it to a lt1460-5?

I would appreciate any input,
thanks a lot!
[image: created schematic]

Comment: I'll only add this thought. Given \$50\:\Omega\$, and considering \$100\:\text{MHz}\$ (\$10\:\text{ns}\$ total cycle time), and considering that you should want your rise and fall times to be about \$\frac1{10}\$th of that in, say, perhaps \$2\tau\$ to \$3\tau\$.... how many \$\text{pF}\$ do you calculate you can drive? (Forget the circuit for now.)

Comment: hi @jonk, thanks for your reply. Hope I'm getting this right. If τ = R*C => C = 2τ/50Ω = 2(1/10 * 10ns)/50Ω = 40pF?

Comment: I get less. The rising edge should be ((10e-9 s)/(50 ohm)) * 0.1 (falling edge, likewise, so that you are left with 80% for the tops and bottoms) and then either divided by 2 or 3, depending on how many taus you want. I'd say 7-10 pF.

Comment: Q1 will charge your output load quickly. What will R5 do?

Comment: @jonk yes you are right! For now I would change it to 10pF.

Comment: @Neil_UK I' guess R5 will not change quickly? To what value should it be cut down? 50 to 150 ohms?

Comment: BFR92 not a good output device. 3.3 V at 50 ohm = 66 mA, BFR92 ICmax 25 mA. It's got a 5 GHz bandwidth, it's likely to oscillate in emitter follower configuration without a base stopper. What's that 50 ohm load? Is it meant to be a pure resistive load? Jonk was discussing load capacitance. Your output impedance at the moment is a few ohms on the rising edge, and 1 kohm on the falling edge, which will make a mess into any load capacitance. Wouldn't you rather have a 50 ohm output impedance? I would use logic throughout, to make the short pulses, and parallel some drivers for the output device.

Comment: @Neil_UK the 50ohm load will be replaced with a laser diode. This circuit should create short nansosecond pulses for the laser diode to create picosecond light pulses (gain switching). How can I create with only logic short pulses? and what would be an example of "parallel some drivers for the output device"? Thanks

Comment: Put a diode in your schematic for the load, not a resistor. What range of pulse lengths do you want? How adjustable? With a knob? With selecting components or switches? All these things matter to an engineering solution.

Comment: @Neil_UK thanks a lot for trying to help with the schematic. The pulse lengths should be in the ballpark of 2.5ns (zero to zero), and don't need to be adjustable - if adjustable it would be ok to be one time set with fixed components capacitors/resistors (min lenght would be 1ns and max lenght around 5ns). In a further extension I'm planing to add a trigger/clock schematic, which will be feeding the circuit and provide an output for triggering. The repetition rate of the trigger signal will still be in the 20-80Mhz range, selectable with a prescaler - no other user input planed.

Answer (score 1):

Taking a risk on misunderstanding your load, I'd suggest the following

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2f9ALak.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

If your output is a laser diode, then your drive to it should be a current source. You can use slower, higher current transistors in the output than your suggested BRF92, which is too weedy for your output, and too lively to be used as an emitter follower. Connected like this, you will get most of the advertised ft out of the transistors. Choose R1 with the supply voltage to set your load current.

The use of PECL (that is, ECL driven from +5 V instead of -5 V) in the pulse-forming stage has a number of advantages. It's about the right speed for your use. The LTC6752 is a bit slow for your suggested output pulse lengths. ECL is fairly tame when driven with delays like the RC shown. If you don't like the idea of a slow edge into the next gate, then as your delay is only a few nS, you could replace the RC with two or three feet of transmission line (with appropriate termination) to get the delay, RG178 is nice and thin, or a synthetic delay line from a few Ls and Cs. PECL has the right output voltage to directly drive the output current switch. Each positive going input edge will produce a positive going pulse.

U1 is some complementary ECL output gate, perhaps a TTL to PECL converter/level shifter.

Comment: it is a great suggestion. Since I failed selecting a comperator, can you suggest TTL to PECL converter as well as a PECL? Perferable from Analog/LT since I wanted to do the simulation in LTSpice. For Q1/Q2 I would have choosen a MMBT5551? Does this seem reasonable?

Comment: mmbt5551 looks awful, they're dog slow, and their gain collapses beyond a few 10s of mA. Why a 5551, was it the first one you found in a list?

Comment: fast pnps seem to be harder to find than when I was using them decades ago. I looked at Digikey, filtered on 'available in 1s', as well as DC current, voltage and speed, and 30A02CH and 2SAR502U3T106 are about the least worst. They may be fast enough for your application. See if you can find models for them, and simulate what you get, with reasonable estimates for parasitic capacitance of the diode and connections.

Comment: I only MMBT5551 in mind since I think I have a package of them. I haven't found for the 30A02CH and 2SAR502U3T106 any Ltspice models. But first I wanted to create the digital part, and I'm not sure which parts to choose. For the level shifter I would have choosen a MAX9371 and for the AND gate a MC10EL05, does this make sense (wouldn't be able to simulate it with ltspice since there are no models for these)?

Comment: @ulix Yes, both of those parts look fine. Are you able to operate your laser diode from a fixed positive rail with a current pulled out of the -ve terminal. If so, an NPN output long-tailed pair gives you many many more transistors to choose from in the appropriate 1 or 2 GHz ft range.

Comment: around 50mA should be fine in your circuit at I_out. The rest of ca. 100mA will be provided by a 15V rail/current source - adjustable. So keeping the diode current constant at 50mA and injecting spikes of another 50mA from the pulser.

Comment: @ulix That comment confirms current drive is appropriate, but says nothing about polarity. Would you answer the polarity question please, can you use an NPN configured longtailed pair as the current switch?

Comment: Sorry I skiped that. It should be no problem to provide a -ve rail. Thanks a lot, ulix

Comment: Do you think OnSemi NPN NSVF5488SK/NSVF5501SK/MCH4009 or Infineon's BFR380L3 would be good choices? Would there be a transitor alternative configuration other than a long-tailed pair?

Comment: Datasheets are here: [NSVF5488SK](https://www.mouser.de/datasheet/2/308/NSVF5488SK_D-1813771.pdf) [NSVF5501SK](https://www.mouser.de/datasheet/2/308/NSVF5501SK_D-1813997.pdf) [MCH4009](https://www.mouser.de/datasheet/2/308/ENA0389-D-1804724.pdf) [BFR380L3](https://www.mouser.de/datasheet/2/196/Infineon-BFR380L3-DS-v01_01-en-1225959.pdf)

Comment: @ulix either of the NSVs looks OK. Use 10 ohms in series with the base to guard against them taking off